# PHP Fake require_once to always return true

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Is it possible to "fake" the inclusion of a file ?

I am testing a code base where DI hasn't been implemented and want to include a class file with my own version before it gets required. When it hits the actual require line, I get complaints about the class already being added.

So when I do `require_once` on the file, I don't want to actually include it, but it to carry on like it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to duplicate the project and change directory before including the configuration files containing require statements: except in the copied directory, the files were empty.
Then I switched back to the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `include_once()` which won't give you breaking errors but will still try and include the file.